# How does one see connectedness of a covering space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Something can be proven about the loops (or their possible lifts?) in the base space which will ensure connectivity of the cover?

Comment: ... you are assuming the base is connected, yes?

Answer (score 3):

a) If the base space  $X$  is connected, nothing  will ensure the (non)connectivity of a covering:
The identity $1_X:X\to X$ is always a  connected covering and given a connected covering  $Y\to X$ the obvious covering $Y\sqcup Y\to X$ is a non connected  covering of $X$.

b) If you start with a disconnected space $X$ every surjective covering of $X$ will be disconnected.
However some definitions of "covering space" (the right ones in my opinion) allow non surjective covering spaces .
In that context the inclusion $X_i\hookrightarrow X$ of a connected component $X_i$ of $X$  is a connected covering space of $X$.

Comment: I have heard stuff like, if you can find a loop in the base space such that it lifts to a loop in a non-trivial way then the cover is connected.  Can be stated in some homology terms? Can you explain?

Comment: The stuff you heard is false because you can always add to  any connected covering space,  satisfying whatever condition on loops you want, a disjoint copy of itself and get a non connected covering. Homology has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Elencwaig Okay - something along these lines - that for a 2-covering there has to be a homomorphism from he first homology group to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ which satisfies some properties? Like that there should be at least one loop in the base space which is mapped to $-1$ by this? (for n-lifts I think something is required about the map from the first homology group to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to be surjective?)